# T-SQL: Extract section of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

A column in a table contains a standard text like follows:

```
Variable Length Text (12345) follows more  variable length text again.
```

My target is to select that 12345, or actually the number between ( ) as also that number can be of different length.
Any recommendation, please?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(TcSubjectTx_N, CHARINDEX('(', TcSubjectTx_N)+1, CHARINDEX(')', TcSubjectTx_N)-CHARINDEX('(', TcSubjectTx_N)-1)
FROM T_TcTicket
WHERE TcTicketID=78945
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUBSTRING()` function and `CHARINDEX()` function as below :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(<Column>, CHARINDEX('(', <Column>)+1, CHARINDEX(')', <Column>)-CHARINDEX('(', <Column>)-1);
```

**Output :**

```
12345
```

**Note** : This will give you All string/numbers between `(` and `)`

Comment: Tnx, but that throws an error `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function`

Comment: tnx again that is exactly what I did, attempt query added to my original question.

Comment: @DeepDiver i think your column doesnt contain the data with ().

Comment: well spotted, I had indeed selected the wrong column name. All works now, tnx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*, v2.exp
from t cross apply
     (values (stuff(t.col, 1, charindex('(', t.col + '('), ''))
     ) v1(exp) cross apply
     (values (left(v1.exp, charindex(')', v1.exp + ')') - 1 ))
     ) v2(exp);
```

Note:  This gets everything between the first opening paren and closing paren.

[Here](http://rextester.com/HILS24317) is a rextester.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE 
@STRING VARCHAR(MAX)=
'Variable Length Text (12345) follows more  variable length text again.'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@STRING,
             CHARINDEX('(',@STRING)+1,
             (CHARINDEX(')',@STRING)-1)-CHARINDEX('(',@STRING)
                )
```